# Want to Show Image and Text side by side in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android development, I am building an app and on that I want to show Imageview and Textview side by side in android layout. Below code is showing textview below the imagview. Here I am using linearlayout.

In this layout I am showing some data from database.

**Expected layout design:**

```
Imageview Text1
          Text2
```

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="com.example.spand.krishnasoftwares.Main2Activity">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="20px"
        android:id="@+id/vly">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:src="@drawable/gym_logo1"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/ly1">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Exercise 1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginTop="20px"
                android:textSize="10dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ly1"
            android:paddingLeft="5px"
            android:paddingRight="5px"
            android:id="@+id/ly2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Exercise Name:"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginTop="20px"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/en1"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginTop="20px"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ly2"
            android:id="@+id/ly3"
            android:paddingLeft="5px"
            android:paddingRight="5px"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Speed: "
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginTop="10px"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/es1"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginTop="10px"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ly3"
            android:paddingLeft="5px"
            android:paddingRight="5px"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/ly4">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Repetition: "
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginTop="10px"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/erep1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10px"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textDirection="ltr" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/erep2"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginTop="10px"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/erep3"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginTop="10px"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ly4"
            android:paddingLeft="5px"
            android:paddingRight="5px"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/ly5">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Weight: "
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginTop="10px"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ew1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10px"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textDirection="ltr" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: dont use nested layout when using ConstraintLayout . you are killing whole purpose of ConstraintLayout.

Comment: You haven't added links to your expected output

Comment: http://wiresareobsolete.com/2016/07/constraintlayout-part-1/ study this tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this.. It will creates layout view hows you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/vly"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="20px"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/add" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ly"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ly1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20px"
                    android:text="Exercise 1"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textSize="10dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ly2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ly1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="5px"
                android:paddingRight="5px">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20px"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Exercise Name:" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/en1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20px"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ly3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ly2"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="5px"
                android:paddingRight="5px">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Speed: " />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/es1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ly4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ly3"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="5px"
                android:paddingRight="5px">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Repetition: " />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/erep1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
                    android:layout_weight="1"

                    android:textDirection="ltr" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/erep2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/erep3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ly5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ly4"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="5px"
                android:paddingRight="5px">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Weight: " />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ew1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
                    android:layout_weight="1"

                    android:textDirection="ltr" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Welcome, Keep coding.. :)

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use drawable left?

Use drawable left in first text-view and with proper padding between drawable and text you can easily achieve what you intend.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       tools:context="com.example.spand.krishnasoftwares.Main2Activity">

           <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Exercise 1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/"
            android:layout_marginTop="20px"
            android:textSize="10dp"/>
      </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

BENEFITS:
    You can save extra nesting of multiple view groups.
    Lesser rendering time in case of recycler view or list view.
    Recommended by Google developers resource.

Comment: @AshishJohn Even in that case he can use multiple text views aligning them in constraint layout and can use drawableLeft.                                               
    Imageview Text1
                    Text2  <<<<< This need can easily be and should be done without Nesting.Frames Saved is speed delivered.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use ConstraintLayout in this way, follow the this code;

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi alicanozkara, now when i put extra textview it did not show exactly what my requirements is.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like @drawable/gym_logo1 is the child of @+id/vly LinearLayout that has android:orientation="vertical". You should try making it the child of @+id/ly1

Answer (score 0):

Create your layout like this it'll work for you...but remind one thing search first if you don't get solution then ask...

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/colorBackground">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/gym_logo1"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="20px"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:id="@+id/vly">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/ly1">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Exercise 1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginTop="20px"
            android:textSize="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ly1"
        android:paddingLeft="5px"
        android:paddingRight="5px"
        android:id="@+id/ly2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Exercise Name:"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginTop="20px"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/en1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginTop="20px"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ly2"
        android:id="@+id/ly3"
        android:paddingLeft="5px"
        android:paddingRight="5px"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Speed: "
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginTop="10px"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/es1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginTop="10px"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ly3"
        android:paddingLeft="5px"
        android:paddingRight="5px"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/ly4">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Repetition: "
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginTop="10px"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/erep1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textDirection="ltr" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/erep2"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginTop="10px"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/erep3"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginTop="10px"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ly4"
        android:paddingLeft="5px"
        android:paddingRight="5px"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/ly5">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Weight: "
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginTop="10px"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ew1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textDirection="ltr" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your .xml to

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorBackground">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="20px"
            android:id="@+id/vly">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:src="@drawable/gym_logo1"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/ly1">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Exercise 1"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20px"
                    android:textSize="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Exercise Name:"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20px"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/en1"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20px"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Speed: "
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/es1"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Repetition: "
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/erep1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textDirection="ltr" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/erep2"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/erep3"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Weight: "
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ew1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textDirection="ltr" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

`