# Display multiple elements in card-like disposition with a loop - Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, card

I'm fairly new with Android development so I'm just trying some concepts.

For this POC I took the first 20 values from this IMDB list => https://www.imdb.com/chart/toptv/

added them into a JSON which is inside the assets folder of my project.
I have a method in my main activity to access the content of the JSON file, it goes like this:

```
  public void readMovies() {
    String jsonFileString = Utils.getJsonFromAssets(getApplicationContext(), "movies.json");
    Log.i("data", jsonFileString);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type listUserType = new TypeToken<List<Movies>>() { }.getType();


    List<Movies> movies = gson.fromJson(jsonFileString, listUserType);
    for (int i = 0; i < movies.size(); i++) {
        Log.i("data", "> Item " + i + "\n" + movies.get(i));
    }
}
```

Using a textView I'm able to output all the titles (for example) in the layout, but I'd like to be able to display a view similar to the IMDB page, with an image to the left side, title on the centre and any other property on the right side.

[image]

How can I achieve a view like the shared URL?

Comment: You need to design a separate UI for that, with placeholders for image and text.

Comment: If you search for something like "android listview with images" you can find a million and one tutorials on this.

Comment: @ram I thought so, but how do I populate multiple elements of the layout using the same loop?

Comment: Thank you @KenY-N I'm not familiar with Android semantics so that search criteria should work.

Comment: The best way to implement that is to use **RecyclerView with Cards**.<br>
If you go through these 2 videos you will completely understand RecyclerView in Java [**Part1**](https://youtu.be/18VcnYN5_LM) and [**Part2**](https://youtu.be/xgpLYwEmlO0) <br> For any other doubts related to Cards refer to the Material Cards Documentation - [**Material Cards**](https://material.io/components/cards)<br>
To learn more about RecyclerView [Here is a Codelab by Google(Kotlin)](https://developer.android.com/courses/pathways/android-basics-kotlin-unit-2-pathway-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to create a `Listview` with images and text. Attaching some resources.

1. Checkout the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45670385/want-to-show-image-and-text-side-by-side-in-android) Stack overflow question
2. Check out this [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRPpQw0dzko) tutorial or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_YF6ocdPaBg) one.

These are the ones I found which provide a code walk-through. But now you know the keywords to search for, you can find resources on your own!

Comment: Thank you @ram, this got me in the right direction which is what I needed, having the right search criteria is pretty important!